# React Native app could not open after success install in my phone

Tags: android, react-native

I was trying to run my React Native app on my physical Android phone. I successfully run it and install it in my phone, however when I tap the icon and try to open the app, it shows a white screen then close back immediately. What was I doing wrong?

My Android Phone version is 8.0.0 and it do not have any internet connection.

The command `react-native run android` gave me final output as below:

```
Installed on 1 device.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 20s
51 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 48 up-to-date
info Connecting to the development server...
info Starting the app on "8UEDU17C..."...
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.sampleproject/.MainActivity }
```

Can I know what's wrong?

Comment: Make sure you have followed the steps here https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device#running-your-app-on-android-devices

Comment: Check the logs using 'react-native log-android'. This will show you the logs and hope you can find out the error.

Comment: is bundle server running ..? do react-native start first then react-native run-android

Comment: If you found solution please provide it to help others.